# Buy or download Plesk theme

Tags: themes, plesk, parallels

Any Plesk themes available to download or buy?

I like the default skin but I want something else for my clients.

Can someone be of any help?

I tried googling but couldn't find pre-made themes.

Thanks in advance,
Cherif

Comment: This type of question (tool/resource recommendation) is off-topic for StackOverflow

Answer (score -1):

There is the extension

[Plesk Skins and Color Schemes](https://ext.plesk.com/packages/4bbd82c3-499e-4061-8b80-2794ff3f48bc-heavy-metal-skin)

and the additional official Plesk documentation:

[Plesk Onyx official documentation: Using Custom Themes](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/administrator-guide/customizing-the-plesk-interface/using-custom-themes.70906/)

Comment: I know. But I would like a custom theme build because I dont have the time to put all the work into it.